# Getting "Whitelabel Error Page" when opening "/actuator/mappings"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm new to spring-cloud, so i'm using a video tutorial, so to read exposed endpoints i tried to open http://localhost:8000/actuator/mappings but it didn't work for me but the /health url gave me the following result:

[image]

Here's the written code in the client side:

```
@RefreshScope
@RestController
class MessageRestController {

  @Value("${message}")
  private String message;

  @RequestMapping("/message")
  String getMessage() {
      return this.message;
  }
 }
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.spring.cloud.reservation</groupId>
<artifactId>reservation-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>reservation-service</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's the client project structure:

[image]

**bootstrap.properties:**

```
spring.application.name=reservation-service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

When executing the Post on the /refresh gives me : **Error Not Found**

```
curl -d {} http://localhost:8000/actuator/refresh
```

[image]

**spring-boot-actuator jar version = 2.1.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Default  management.endpoints.web.exposure.include, info, health`
As `actuator/health` and actuator/info are provided by default you will get the information

> management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = *  //will allow all endpoints
>   to be exposed

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info # Endpoint IDs that should be included or '*' for all.
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude= # Endpoint IDs that should be excluded or '*' for all.
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator # Base path for Web endpoints. Relative to server.servlet.context-path or management.server.servlet.context-path if management.server.port is configured.
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping= # Mapping between endpoint IDs and the path that should expose them.
```

**Securing Endpoint**

```
management.endpoint.health.roles= # Roles used to determine whether or not a user is authorized to be shown details. When empty, all authenticated users are authorized. //for health

management.endpoint.health.show-details=always,never # When to show full health details.
```

**Enable/Disable endpoints**

```
management.endpoint.(endpointName).enabled=true # Whether to enable the health endpoint.
e.g. management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot 2.x :: only health and info is exposed by default, In order to expose other actuator endpoint either mention the endpoint name or add following line to expose all endpoints.

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: '*'

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Spring boot 2.x, all actuator endpoints are disabled except for few non sensitive endpoints like /health and /info by default.

You can enable them using property `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`

Please refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-enabling-endpoints) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do post, e.g
curl -X POST xxx.yyy.zzz:8080/actuator/refresh